# Drupal Views Infinite Scroll

Tags: drupal, drupal-views, infinite-scroll

I have inherited a website, through work, and I ran into a minor issue that I have trouble figuring out.

The thing is this: I have a Views block with lots of fields that link to galleries and youtube clips. The format is Grid and show as Fields. Ajax is turned off, and the page works fine, exept from the the infinite scroll. I cant get it to work....and it works perfectly on all the other subpages on the site.

The page is called: http://www.roddin.fo/media

Any help would be much obliged!

Comment: That media page is totally different that those other where scroll works. It has different layout. If you want it to work like other page make it in the same content type. Usually content type can be seen as a class of body tag, but it's not printed here, so I can't tell you what content type it is.

Comment: I can see that all the content is wrapped in quick tabs, so this can be your problem.